# Non-SSL site making API call to SSL site

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I apologize, I know this is a very short question but Google doesn't seem to help (I guess I'm not searching for the correct phrase or set of keywords).

If I have a site not protected by SSL and it makes an api call to an https site, is that information secure or do I need to have SSL as well?

I want to make sure I keep my users' data secure.

Only data in the API call (request) needs to be protected. Data returned by the API (response) to my (non-SSL) site isn't meaningful or sensitive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No SSL -> no security.  If the information passing through that connection isn't "meaningful or sensitive", then you might not need SSL. But it's not going to affect the data that's generated at the first server, and passed thru SSL to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to the SSL site will be protected, but if it's multihop (client to non SSL to SSL site) and the data on first hop is plain text.

However as @VictorRonin says, security is a much bigger concern than just SSL.

Comment: Thanks Preet. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The call is protected. Your website talking to another website (protected by SLL) will send and get information inside of protected  channel.

However, it's hard to say whether your users data is secure. Security requires a lot more than just usage of SSL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm taking steps to secure the rest of the page and process as well and my main concern at the moment is transmission of sensitive data over a non-ssl connection. So if I understand correctly, as long as one site has SSL, transmission of data upstream and downstream are both protected?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problems.

I'm using 16 bits micro connect to net by Wifi's AT command .

after connected in transparent mode. normally I can send some simple text (HTTP ) to request content from every web page.(if those webpages not need SSL).

this makes programing fun and easy.

But these few years. life got stuck almost webpage use SSL. mean programming need more complex step to reach content.

but the most serious things is that the CA (cert auth) cannot use forever it has expired time !!!

This mean hardware device have to modified CA data frequently . so it's not practical for small iot firm .

However I found a way even it's not the best by using thingspeak.com (ThingHTTP)

with ThingHTTP you can request without SSL to any website which need SSL

I hope in the future there are more iot cloud or even some webpage turn to use old method (HTTP) in case of that data no need secure.

In my opinion user can encode/decode the data by themself instead of secure everything in webpage.

Thnks